# AngularJS appending links after encoding forward slash -

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`http://localhost/templateStore/app/#!/templates` - Works fine .

After clicking on the link on the current page the link gets transformed to this : `http://localhost/templateStore/app/#!/templates#%2Ftemplates%2F1`

This should be : `http://localhost/templateStore/app/#!/templates/1`

**Link Definition** for the details button :

```
`<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-href="#/templates/1">Details</a>`
```

> Issues

Forward slash is getting encoded to "`%2F`"  and you can see an additional "`/templates`" appended to the URL created by Angular.

> I am using an UBUNTU 15.04

see the codes for app.js and template.js  :

**app.js**

```
angular.module('templateStore', [
  'ngRoute',
  'templateStore.view1',
  'templateStore.view2',
  'templateStore.templates'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/templates'});
}]);
```

**template.js**

```
angular.module('templateStore.templates',['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/templates',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/templates.html',
            controller: 'TemplateCtrl'
        }).
        when('/templates/:templateId',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/template-details.html',
            controller: 'TemplateDetailsCtrl',

        })

    }])

    .controller('TemplateCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
        console.log('TemplateCtrl Init ');
        console.log($scope);
    }])
    .controller('TemplateDetailsCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
        console.log('TemplateDetailsCtrl Init ');
        console.log($scope);
        alert('TemplateDetailsCtrl');
    }]);
```

*Please let me know how to fix this.*

see the screenshots below

**Landing Page**

[image]

**See the link on the bottom left corner when hovering on the details button**

[image]

**See what happened after clicking the details button :**

[image]

Template Details page : This can be viewed when we enter the URL as `http://localhost/templateStore/app/#!/templates/1`

[image]

Comment: Show click handler or link definition in HTML, please

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-href="#/templates/1">Details</a>

Comment: you should use gimp before you post screenshots, to show us only a part of your screen.

Comment: try `<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-href="/templates/1">Details</a>` (remove the `#` sign from your `ng-href` directive)

Comment: @Iulian, it changes the URL to localhost/templates/1 and when clicking on that it goes to localhost/templates/1 which is not available.

Comment: @Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant ::  acknowledged  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Removed `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`  and it is working .

```
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); // deleted this line . 

 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/templates'});
}]);
```